# Get domain address of calling webpage in PHP

Tags: php

I want to apply check only a specific website domain can hit my site. I tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but i am getting the full url.But i just want the domain address like `www.example.com` not all the url. I tried to explode but in the start i am getting `http:\\` so when i explode on \ this .It explode the http section as well. Is there any other way so i can get on the domain url.

if the url is http://www.example.com/test.php i only want http://www.example.com. I have also used explode but explode function explode the http/ section first.I want the url of another website who's hitting my website

Comment: Then parse / it or split it up so you can check the part you're interested in. To be honest though, it's not a reliable field, so better to find an alternative solution.

Comment: Please be more specific of what you want. Your question is a lot confusing..

Comment: I want the url like http://www.example.com. not full url.

Comment: https://php.net/parse_url

Comment: I want to give permission to a specific site can hit my website . So when i get the calling website url . i am getting the full url but i only need http://www.example.com section.

Comment: Please read the comments. And again, HTTP_REFERER is not reliable.

Comment: then how i can get the calling website address. @Jonnix

Comment: You could for example check the REMOTE_ADDR value against a known IP address / range for the service you're wanting to limit requests from.

Comment: Please update your question. You have stated a couple of times now that you want `example.com` as a result, yet in your question you include both `www.` and `protocol` parts. However, you should be perfectly able to do what you want by now with the info in the comments. Do you have a *specific* problem ? Post what you've tried.

Comment: Another website is hitting my site and i want the hitting website url only like http://www.example.com not the full address with index.php etc. I have tried http_referer but it return me the full url with index.php or any other page.

Comment: should i explain it more ?

Comment: @Jonnix Yes, `HTTP_REFERER` is not reliable since is set by the user agent, but I'm afraid is the best he can do. Following a link will set it to the origin domain somewhat allowing him to prevent hotlinking, but using `REMOTE_ADDR` as you suggest will effectively *block all traffic*, since it will hold the **client** ip.

Comment: Yeah, that was kind of the point. You want to restrict to a specific site / service, HTTP_REFERER is absolutely not the way. As we've said, it's not reliable, but additionally since we're talking about access restrictions, it's not secure. Stopping access from everything aside from this service is what I'm reading OP wants. There are plenty of other options to secure this kind of communication, but without knowing anything about the other side, with with few details on OP's side, it's hard to suggest alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have 2 two websites one is hosting Microsoft sharepoint site and other is hosting php site.I want to allow only my sharepoint site can access my other site for some functionality . But the problem is i am not getting any http referer in header from sharepoint site.

Answer (score 0):

```
$hitting_url=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$site_url=parse_url($hitting_url, PHP_URL_HOST);

if($site_url != 'www.example.com')
{
    header('Location:'.$hitting_url);
    exit();
}
```

I have fix the issue with parse_url.